# Android Can't setup Device , Contact Your It Admin, getting this error in new phones, while qr code is working fine in old phones

Tags: android, enterprise, emm

I am creating a device policy manager app, its working fine in old device till android 10, but on higher versions while scanning qrcode its giving the error , can't setup device, contact your it admin for help.

Comment: I am getting the same also on a new phone. tested number of times on my other phones

Comment: Try to follow logic from this repo: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc. If I'm not mistaken from Android 10 you need to apply ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE and GET_PROVISIONING_MODE intent actions in Manifest